# inputted list keeps being interpreted as string

Tags: python

So I made this little code at school, and i know that input() can understand lists as is. I tried it again at home but it doesnt work. My school computer has python 2. something while my laptop has 3.4.

The code looks like this

```
a = input()
list = []
count = 0
for y in range(1, len(a)):
    min = a[count]
    for x in range(count +1, len(a)):
        if min > a[x]:
            min = a[x]

    print(min)
    a[count] = min  #str object does not support item assignment
    count=count+1

print (a)
```

I want to input a list such as [1,2,3,4,5] but what happens is, it reads the whole thing as a string, along with the commas, when i want to see it as a list of integers.

Comment: Can you show your typical input and expected output?

Comment: I'm sorry, really new here. I want to just arrange the inputted list in descending order. the last line has to be print(a) not print(list).

Comment: The meaning of `input` changed between Python 2 and Python 3.  On python 2, use `raw_input`, and you will see the same behaviour

Comment: what should i do so python would see the input as a list?

Comment: There is very little reason to do so, data does not normally come in that format.  See the solutions below.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didnt really know. This community is awesome, by the way. I have been seeing so many talent in here. I hope I become as good as you someday lol. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3's `input` returns a string (same as Python 2's `raw_input`), whilst Python 2's `input` evaluates the text. To get similar behaviour, if you've got a valid Python list that can be evaluated, then you can use `ast.literal_eval`, eg:

```
import ast

a = ast.literal_eval(input())
# do other stuff with `a` here...
```

So you'd enter something like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as your input, and you'll end up with `a` being a Python list.

Comment: Thanks! I really was sure its about the input function and not just me lol. I think the best solution is to change to python 2, so the professor wont think im using stackoverflow lol. Thanks again! :)

Comment: You can also use the `eval()` function, but that poses some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input would be something like: `"1 2 3 4 5"` -- judging by the code which comes later. This oufcourse is a string. If you want to work with the numbrs in the string as integers you need to:

```
a = input()
a = map(int, a.split())
```